# What muscles are worked by “reverse dips “?

Tags: muscle, calisthenics, anatomy

Imagine being upside down with one’s shoulders resting on some dip bars and elbows bent beside the ribs pointing upwards with forearms coming back down for hands to also grip the bars. So it’s like a shoulder stand on the dip bars stabilised by the hands. And then extending the arms/ elbows to go back and forth into and out of a hand stand from there. What muscles would be worked by such an exercise?

Would it be triceps and upper pecs as normal dips are largely triceps and lower pecs?

Comment: Wait, is this basically just like a modified pike push up?

Answer (score 4):

That's a [handstand pushup](https://exrx.net/WeightExercises/DeltoidAnterior/BWHandstandPressBench). The primary muscles worked are the anterior deltoids and the triceps. The upper pecs would also contribute, but not as much as the deltoids.